# mktime failure on windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

Using visual studio 2013, creating a standard win32 console application, mktime returns negative(-1) regardless of params passed.

Are there any reasons this code should fail this way? I can't tell that any combination of tm params passed makes any difference.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct tm stm;
    stm.tm_sec = 27;
    stm.tm_min = 5;
    stm.tm_hour = 18;
    stm.tm_mday = 2;
    stm.tm_mon = 1;
    stm.tm_year = 2015;
    stm.tm_wday = 0;
    stm.tm_yday = 0;
    printf("%lld\n", mktime(&stm));//prints -1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to subtract 1900 from the year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value `2015` for `stm.tm_year` is invalid. Subtract `1900` es explained in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kys1801b.aspx).

Note that the month values start with 0 for January.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that and the months being zero based, thanks.  Your link is to a non english page.